# transferring int values into dict; TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to transfer int values in the first column of 'fwd' into a new dict 'fragment_dict' but this type error appeared as I ran my code: "'int' object is not subscriptable". I wonder what's the issue.

```
fwd = {1:1, 2:10, 3:100, 5:10000, 103: 103, 204:204, 205:205, 387:387}


fragment_dic = {}
count = 0

for fragment_num in range(0, 388, 1):
    for pos in range(1,101, 1):
        if fwd == int:
            print()
            genomic_position = fragment_num*100 + pos
            count += fwd[genomic_position] 
        elif fwd != int:
            pass
        fragment_dic[fragment_num] = count
        count = 0
        for i in fwd:    
            fwd[fragment_dic] = i[0]
```

Comment: None of this code makes any sense at all. `fwd` is a dict, it will never be an integer; even if it was, `fwd == int` isn't the way to check that an object is an int (you mean `isinstance(fwd, int)`); an elif that just does `pass` is completely pointless; and the actual error is because iterating through a dict gives you the keys, so `i` is the key.

Comment: It helps if you include the full error message, in particular the bit where it shows you the line `fwd[fragment_dic] = i[0]` which means all we have to do is glance at the error to see it is complaining that you cannot subscript `i` because it is an `int`. Which is what you would expect as it is one of the keys of `fwd`.

Comment: Did your error come with a stack trace? that told you what line the problem was on?

Comment: Thanks @vaultah for the edit. I'm pretty new in StackOverflow :( will follow the format accordingly from now onwards.

Comment: @Duncan I think I will have to look for thoroughly though, I'll try to juggle around few more times..

Comment: sorry guys, I just started on python couple of weeks back, I will try to be more cautious with my coding, especially when uploading questions on the website...

Answer (score 0):

The full error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/t.py", line 18, in <module>
    fwd[fragment_dic] = i[0]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

So either `fwd` (a `dict`) or `i` (a key of that `dict`) is an `int`. They keys of `fwd` are indeed `int` so that's why you get the error.

Comment: Thanks @Duncan for the succinct explanations!

Comment: @KangSanKim Mark the question as resolved by accepting Duncan's answer please.